# How can i export unity games to android?

Tags: unity, android, eclipse

I'm using unity 4.0. I want to build games for android. When I click build it opens a select folder dialog box and wants an apk name. But after pressing select it does nothing. Simply the dialog box closes and nothing. No apk is found in that directory. I also tried 'Export as Eclipse Project'. But that also do the same. Nothing!!!
It's just killing me. What can I do?

Comment: It's extremely difficult to diagnose what your problem might be in this case. Do you have any logs, error output, et cetera that might be appropriate? Otherwise I think you may need to pose this question on another site.

Answer (score 5):

1. Check your Unity Preferences / External Tools / Android SDK Location, according to the Unity docs regarding [Android SDK Setup](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html).
   [image]
2. Check your Build Settings (it's important to check that you've added all the scenes and the starting scene at the beginning)
   [image]
3. Write down the name of the apk file **and click save**
   [image]
4. You should see a new window for showing the building process progress (if it doesn't appear, something is wrong)
   [image]
5. The apk file is ready, if everything else went well